How to translate hierarchical linear model random effects into SEM path diagram?
I've been struggling with translating random slope and intercept and random variables and understanding them as latent variables in the pursuit of path models.
For example here is a random slope and random intercept model of say students nested in schools. Using hierarchal notation:
$$
Y_{ij} = \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1j} X_{ij} + e_{ij}
$$
$$
\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + U_{0j}
$$
$$
\beta_{1j} = \gamma_{10} + U_{1j}
$$
Translating this into path diagram I have latent variables the $U_{0j}$ random intercept and $U_{1j}$ to indicate the random slope. I am not sure how to connect them to other parts of the diagram in the student level.


I believe the article below (Curran & Bauer, 2007) is what you are looking for.  https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=1b09eb97b9998ec06545e5d3ebeec1467dcf658c

From my reading there are two reasons to convert a hlm into a path diagram. For a visual representation of the model that is seen (Curran & Bauer, 2007). My interests were in the estimation of SEM. (Paras & Neale, 2005) offers this guidance.
Following guidance the random intercept and slope $U_{0j}$ and $U_{1j}$ are circles to represent latent variables. $X$ and $Y$ are manifest variables and in boxes. The one triangle represents the intercept. I denoted with greek symbols what each path is estimating. How $U_{0j}$ connects with $Y$ is with a fixed value of 1. $U_{1j}$ connects with $Y$ with the value of $X$. Paras & Neale refer to this as a definition variable. The factor loading is the observation's value of $X$.

For how to estimate this model in OpenMx see: How to fit random slope hierarchical model as SEM with OpenMx in R?
References
Mehta, P. D., & Neale, M. C. (2005). People are variables too: multilevel structural equations modeling. Psychological methods, 10(3), 259.
Curran, P. J., & Bauer, D. J. (2007). Building path diagrams for multilevel models. Psychological Methods, 12(3), 283.
